# How to throw away data value from textbox to textbox in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my coding program in C#. I would like to Scan QR Code data using Handy Terminal and throw out the data value from the textbox that I use for scanning QR Code to another textbox automatically when scanning the QR Code without using Click Event.

[image]

As additional information, The column that filled with numbers 52 and 9 are columns for trimming QR Code text.

And this is my code;

```
private void txtQRCODE_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string QR = txtQRCODE.Text;
    int from_index = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int no_of_characters = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    string result_string = null;
    result_string = QR.Substring(from_index, no_of_characters);
    txtTEST.Text = result_string.ToString();
}
```

Does anyone here, Could help me to fix this problem, please.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, if you are using WPF you can look around MVVM approach, data binding can solve your problem

Comment: Thank you in advance, but unfortunately I am not using WPF in my program. I use windows form

Comment: is your handler called? Can you post the code that sets the handler?

Comment: I am just using that code. That code is running well if I use Click Event, but I want to set automatically without Click Event.